# Is there a CLI call for Gimp to rebuild the font cache?

Tags: command-line, cache, gimp

When Gimp starts, there can be [a long wait time for font cache rebuilds](https://superuser.com/q/238773/69570).

Is there a way to tell Gimp to do this rebuild, from the commandline without starting the app?

- I see [the docs page for CLI args](https://docs.gimp.org/2.8/en/gimp-fire-up.html#gimp-concepts-running-command-line).  One solution may be to run gimp with `--no-interface` and then kill it.
- a workaround may be to [launch Gimp as `sudo`, once](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/217971/37586).

Thanks for your thoughts.

---

Ideally, this would let people choose to add such a process to their cron / launchctl, as a daily/weekly task.

Comment: There are problems on Windows but I have not experienced such delays on Linux. And it all depends if you are talking about systems fonts (handled by GTK or others) or the fonts added for Gimp exclusive use.

Comment: I'm just looking fora an answer to this question, not workarounds or debugging of cache efficiency.  Assume this is on a system that experiences unavoidable font cache building issues, where pre-caching is a valid strategy.  (FWIW: my target system is a misc OSX version)

Comment: Then I would suggest to state the OS(es) clearly in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GIMP 2.10, this should now be mostly obsolete - the interface comes up even if the font cache is still being built, and only if you want to use the text tools on the image  you might encounter a message pointing that out.

Also, more current versions of the fontconfig library are much less likely to create corrupt font cache, so rebuilds happen less frequently.

Comment: Regarding the time-period in which the question was asked (prior to Gimp 2.10), this is a correct answer, IMO